# Salvar 3 casas decimais no sqlServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Pessoal tenho que salvar 3 casas decimais no meu banco de dados SQLSERVER, porem só esta salvando 2 casas por exemplo tenho um valor 0.456 e ao salvar fica 0.450 no código :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public class TB_ItensPedidoCompra
    {
    public decimal ValorUnitario{ get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string TipoSelecionado { get; set; }

 }
```

Na minha camada do banco esta assim:

```
 bdProduto.ValorUnitario = Convert.ToDecimal(vlUnitario);
```

o valor até `vlUnitario` chega `0.456`, mas quando salva fica `0.450`

Alguém poderia me ajudar

no meu banco editei

```
Nome da coluna = ValorUnitario  Tipo de Dados = decimal(18, 4)
```

Comment: Como está sendo feita a persistência na base dados? insert, procedure... está usando o que na camada de dados? ADO, EF, NHIBERNATE, etc...

Comment: estou usando linq EF e salvo       context.SaveChanges();

Comment: se trocasse o tipo para Double não daria certo?

Comment: Aparentemente a precisão de 2 dígitos é o padrão no EF. Veja o link `https://storiknow.com/entity-framework-decimal-scale-and-precision-convention/` que apresenta uma solução para a mesma situação que você está enfrentando. Basicamente, criar uma nova classe do tipo de atributo, adicioná-la na construção do DbContext em `OnModelCreating` e decorar a propriedade (ValorUnitario) do seu objeto.

Comment: @NatanBarros e porque ele faria algo tão errado?

Comment: Não deu certo não estou conseguindo  decorar a propriedade (ValorUnitario)

Comment: @Maniero Foi apenas uma pergunta, se estar errado, explique o porquê... não achei ruim sua crítica, mas se vai fazer uma crítica a uma pessoa que provavelmente sabe menos que você explique... Falei isso pois quando parei de usar decimal e usei double no meu programa deu certo...

Comment: Eu também só fiz uma pergunta. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101

Comment: Uma pergunta dizendo que é algo errado(em formato de pergunta, que foi ironia)...postei até nos comentários para ver alguém me corrigiria se fosse errado, mas esperava argumentos, obrigado pela sua resposta.

Comment: @NatanBarros mudei a minha variavel para float e resolveu o problema, pensei que tinha uma forma de usar o decimal mais realmente não tem Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @DenilsonAna Por nada...